# if want to modify how the ink handwriting in a page should be implemented

Tags: edit, patch, onenote, inkml

C# OneNote API, if  want to modify how the ink handwriting in a page should be implemented, now the official advance PATCH only supports JSON format data and can only modify the content in HTML, but there is no explanation for the modification of the Ink handwriting, thank you!
(It's been hinting now: 400 bad request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry PATCH ink content in a OneNote page is not yet supported